# Is it possible to exit out of an if-statement and return to an inner for-loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Is there a command to exit an if-statement inside of a inner for-loop and have it only go through that inner for-loop?

ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blah.length; i++) {
    blh = scan.nextDouble();            
    blah[i] = blh;

    if(scores[i] < MIN || scores[i] > MAX_SCORE) {
        errFlag = true;
        System.out.println("ERROR: Enter numbers in the range of " +
            MIN + "-" + MAX_SCORE + "!");
        System.out.print("ERROR: Enter all " + numStudents + " scores again: ");
        errFlag = false;
    }                       
}
```

Comment: what "return to an inner for-loop"  means

Answer (score 10):

You may use label block

```
FOUND: {
    for(Type mt: TypeList)
       if(condtion(mt))
            break FOUND;
    // not found code here
}
```

As per [Java Language Specification 14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

> A labeled statement is executed by executing the immediately contained Statement. If the statement is labeled by an Identifier and the contained Statement completes abruptly because of a break with the same Identifier, then the labeled statement completes normally. In all other cases of abrupt completion of the Statement, the labeled statement completes abruptly for the same reason

Comment: Was just about to post this :) Extra resource if anyone wants to read up about the different branching statements. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't a break without a label do the same thing in this case.

Comment: Slightly different. The part that is commented "not found code here" would execute using a normal break. Of course labels are generally great for when you have multiple nested loops and you want to exit to a specific loop, but in this case it does simply the code a tiny bit too.

Comment: Please refer to this paste to see an example illustrating how it's different: http://pastebin.com/wbihfajj

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to exit the if statement, but stay in the for loop, you can you use the continue statement. It is like a break statement, but it just skips the remaining part of the loop, and continues at the beginning the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Other option:

if you want to skip the further code in the `if` block but do not intend to break the loop, you can extract that code in a new method and return in between (based on desired condition), that way you can achieve your purpose (if I understand the question correctly)